# React Transmit textarea data to add a new post

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello fellow programmers! I don't understand how to extract text from textarea and use it to add new blog posts. It should be like this:

1. User enters information in textarea
2. Clicks on AddPost button
3. Information on the page is updated and new post is added to the page list.

I am just starting to learn React. Thanks for your help. Here is the code I tried to write:

```js
import styles from "./Blog.module.css"
import React from "react"


let addPost = () => {
    let text = textAreaRef.current.value
    
}

let textAreaRef = React.createRef()

const Blogger = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.text}
        </div>
    )

}
const Blog = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <textarea ref={textAreaRef}></textarea>
                <button onClick={addPost}>Add Post</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Blogger />
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
export default Blog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need to learn more about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Blogger = ({ posts }) => {
  return <div>{posts && posts.map((post) => <li>{post}</li>)}</div>;
};

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const addPost = () => {
    setPosts([...posts, data]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <textarea
          value={data}
          onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <button onClick={addPost}>Add Post</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Blogger posts={posts} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Blog;
```